# How to write an event emitter in node.js that let's you create a function "myFunction" but then call either success or failure when it runs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

For example, I have seen functions like this, which are handy to use:

```
myFunction(data).
  success(function() { // success! }).
  fail(function() { // fail! });
```

I can't see an obvious way how to implement that.  Here is my sad attempt after looking at the Node.js docs:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var testEmitter = function(x) {
  var e = new EventEmitter();

  if (x) {
    e.emit('success', 'got: ' + x);
  } else {
    e.emit('failure', 'no x passed')
  }

  return e;
}
```

Obviously, this won't work when you try to call it:

```
testEmitter('hello').
  success(console.log('success!')).
  failure(console.log('failure!'));

  // TypeError: Object #<EventEmitter> has no method 'success'
```

What's the best way to implement this pattern?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be "improved" to:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var testEmitter = function(x) {
  var e = new EventEmitter();

  process.nextTick(function(){
    if (x) {
      e.emit('success', 'got: ' + x);
    } else {
      e.emit('failure', 'no x passed')
    }
   })

  var self = {};
  self.success = function(f) {
    e.on('success',f);
    return self;
  };
  self.failure = function(f) {
    e.on('failure',f);
    return self;
  };
  return self;
};

testEmitter("hello").success(function(results){
  console.log('success!',results);
}).failure(function(error){
  console.log('failure!' + error);
})
```

Comment: Sudsy got us 1/2 way there, lipp brought it home.

Answer (score 2):

How about this? I have used process.nextTick to simulate the async work that you want to do in your function.

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var testEmitter = function(x) {
  var e = new EventEmitter();

  process.nextTick(function(){
      if (x) {
        e.emit('success', 'got: ' + x);
      } else {
        e.emit('failure', 'no x passed')
      }
  })

  return e;
}

testEmitter("hello").on("success", function(results){
    console.log('success!' + results);
}).on("failure", function(error){
    console.log('failure!' + error);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are known as promises or [Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), which are used widely in jQuery.

> The Deferred object, introduced in jQuery 1.5, is a chainable utility object created by calling the `jQuery.Deferred()` method. It can register multiple callbacks into callback queues, invoke callback queues, and relay the success or failure state of any synchronous or asynchronous function.
>
> The Deferred object is chainable, similar to the way a jQuery object is chainable, but it has its own methods. After creating a Deferred object, you can use any of the methods below by either chaining directly from the object creation or saving the object in a variable and invoking one or more methods on that variable.

There are [numerous node modules that implement Deferreds](https://npmjs.org/search?q=deferred).